# Entity Framework Core .Net 6.0 many-to-many. Do not understand how this should work

Tags: entity-framework-core, many-to-many, .net-6.0

We are currently working on a project where we migrate from NHibernate to the Entity Framework Core with .Net 6.0. I've scaffolded the existing database to create a new Code First model and most of the entities I use are just working fine with some tweaking of the code and model context. Now I've come accross a situation that I just don't fully understand. I've read the documentation on the subject and searched the net for answers but is just iludes me totally. It is about a many-to-many construction that was scaffolded like this in the model context:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonToScheduledTimeSlot>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();

            entity.Property(e => e.PersonId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("Person_id")
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            entity.Property(e => e.ScheduledTimeSlotId).HasColumnName("ScheduledTimeSlot_id");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Person)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FKFECEB8CB4EF068");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.ScheduledTimeSlot)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ScheduledTimeSlotId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FKFECEB84E36D0C1");
        });
```

Below is a description of how the many-to-many should work

```
                ScheduledTimeSlot <=    PersonToScheduledTimeSlot                => Person
            |                       |                                           |                       |
Database    |   id                  |   Person_id                               |   id                  |
            |                       |   ScheduledTimeSlot_id                    |                       |
            |                       |                                           |                       |
Code        |                       |   PersonId                                |                       |
            |                       |   ScheduledTimeSlotId                     |                       |
            |                       |                                           |                       |
Context     |                       |   HasColumnName("Person_id")              |                       |
            |                       |   HasColumnName("ScheduledTimeSlot_id")   |                       |
```

I have this LINQ query that should resolve but it does not work.

```
        var slots = _UnitOfWork.Query<ScheduledTimeSlot>()
            .AsNoTracking() // <= No tracking needed for these entities
            .Include(sts => sts.RecordingRequest)
            .Include(sts => sts.Lecturers)
            .Include(sts => sts.Device)
            .ThenInclude(dev => dev.DeviceLocations)
            .Where(sts => sts.Start.Date == date) // Get only items for today
            .ToList()
            .Where(sts => sts.IsRecordingPermitted);
```

The problem is with the `.Include(sts => sts.Lecturers)`, If I leave that out the code works but then the `IsRecordingPermitted` in the last `Where` clause does not produce expected results for it tests for the count of `Lecturers` in the query.

The entities involved are these (leaving out non interesting code):

The table to couple the the Person and ScheduledTimeSlot entities:

```
namespace Wur.WurScheduler.Blazor.Core.Models.Database
{
    public partial class PersonToScheduledTimeSlot
    {
        public int ScheduledTimeSlotId { get; set; }
        public string PersonId { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        public virtual ScheduledTimeSlot ScheduledTimeSlot { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Person Entity:

```
namespace Wur.WurScheduler.Blazor.Core.Models.Database
{
    public partial class Person : EntityWithId
    {
        public ICollection<ScheduledTimeSlot> ScheduledTimeSlots { get; set; }
        
        .....
    }
}
```

The ScheduledTimeSlot entity:

```
namespace Wur.WurScheduler.Blazor.Core.Models.Database
{
    public partial class ScheduledTimeSlot : EntityWithId, IAuditable, IValidatableObject
    {
        public ICollection<Person> Lecturers { get; set; }
        
        ...
    }
}
```

I've tried several scenarios with ForeignKey Attributes and Column attribute but something is wrong and I can't put my finger on it. According to the documentation I should be able to do this (changed the `.WithMany()`:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonToScheduledTimeSlot>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();

            entity.Property(e => e.PersonId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("Person_id")
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            entity.Property(e => e.ScheduledTimeSlotId).HasColumnName("ScheduledTimeSlot_id");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Person)
                .WithMany(person => person.ScheduledTimeSlots)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FKFECEB8CB4EF068");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.ScheduledTimeSlot)
                .WithMany(timeslot => timeslot.Lecturers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ScheduledTimeSlotId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FKFECEB84E36D0C1");
        });
```

But the compiler complains with the following (removed bloated info):

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'ICollection<Wur.WurScheduler.Blazor.Core.Models.Database.ScheduledTimeSlot>' to 'IEnumerable<Wur.WurScheduler.Blazor.Core.Models.Database.PersonToScheduledTimeSlot>'.

Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'ICollection<Wur.WurScheduler.Blazor.Core.Models.Database.Person>' to 'IEnumerable<Wur.WurScheduler.Blazor.Core.Models.Database.PersonToScheduledTimeSlot>'.
```

which to me is not intuitive. I was expecting this to work but for some reason is does not.

Comment: As for EF, you only have two 1:n association. Therefore, both `Person` and `ScheduledTimeSlot` should have collections `public ICollection<PersonToScheduledTimeSlot>`.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold Thanks for responding. Can you elaborate? Do I need to add some code to the context to achieve this or is just adding the 2 collections enough?

Comment: I would just replace (not add) the collections.

Comment: See here for more info and other options in the surrounding text. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#indirect-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @GertArnold But that is just exactly where my code fails. If I add the `.WithMany(person => person.ScheduledTimeSlots)` the compiler complain as described in my post and I can not put my finger on the problem with that. I'm missing something here.

Comment: Yes, please read carefully, the collections should be `PersonToScheduledTimeSlots`, not `ScheduledTimeSlots`.

Comment: @GertArnold Ah, but I didn't mention something here. The solution is a work in progress meaning that the 'fase1' still uses NHibernate while 'fase2' uses EF Core 6.0. I cannot change anything in the database right now because it would make 'fase1' fail.

Comment: @GertArnold `Yes, please read carefully, the collections should be PersonToScheduledTimeSlots, not ScheduledTimeSlots` Do you mean that both the `Lecturers` and `ScheduledTimeSlots` should be collections of the type `PersonToScheduledTimeSlot`?

Comment: @GertArnold Just tried it but now a lot of other code fails to compile because it expects a list of Persons and ScheduledTimeSlots instead of a list of PersonToScheduledTimeSlots.

Comment: You *can* have [many to many associations with so-called *skip navigations*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) which would mean you have collections of `ScheduledTimeSlot` and no `PersonToScheduledTimeSlot` class. You can even have both. It's all described in the docs.

Comment: @GertArnold I know, I've read that documentation. I understand the concept of that but somewhere it just doesn't make my mind switch so I can implement it. I'm missing something and I can't grasp it somehow. I have a lot of knowledgeable colleagues that looked into this problem but none of them came up with a solution. It just needs that little push to get it right.

Comment: @GertArnold I'll look into it tomorrow once more. Thanks so far Gert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who want to know how to do this. Here's a description of my solution.

```
namespace Wur.WurScheduler.Blazor.Core.Models.Database
{
    public partial class Person : EntityWithId
    {
        public ICollection<ScheduledTimeSlot> ScheduledTimeSlots { get; set; }
        // Define a list to the couple table on your entity.
        public List<PersonToScheduledTimeSlot> PersonScheduledTimeSlots { get; set; }

    
        .....
    }
}



namespace Wur.WurScheduler.Blazor.Core.Models.Database
{
    public partial class ScheduledTimeSlot : EntityWithId, IAuditable, IValidatableObject
    {
        public ICollection<Person> Lecturers { get; set; }
        // Do the same on the other entity
        public List<PersonToScheduledTimeSlot> ScheduledTimeSlotPersons { get; set; }
        
        ...
    }
}
```

In the ModelContext add the following to one of the entities involved. In this case I put it on the ScheduledTimeSlot entity.

```
entity.HasMany(sts => sts.Lecturers)
    .WithMany(lec => lec.ScheduledTimeSlots)
    .UsingEntity<PersonToScheduledTimeSlot>(
        j => j
            .HasOne(ptsts => ptsts.Person)
            .WithMany(t => t.PersonScheduledTimeSlots)
            .HasForeignKey(ptsts => ptsts.PersonId),
        j => j
            .HasOne(ptsts => ptsts.ScheduledTimeSlot)
            .WithMany(p => p.ScheduledTimeSlotPersons)
            .HasForeignKey(ptsts => ptsts.ScheduledTimeSlotId),
        j =>
        {
            j.HasKey(t => new { t.PersonId, t.ScheduledTimeSlotId });
        });
```

And remove the `entity.HasNoKey();` from the PersonToScheduledTimeslot model description. Couple tables need a key.